# What kind of external microphone can I use with my Galaxy smartphone?

Tags: video, audio, microphone

I'm feeling a bit stupid.

I want to make video podcasts using my Samsung Galaxy S3 but of course the internal mic isn't much good.

So i need an external mic.

Can I use pretty much any battery-powered mic and plug it into my phone (maybe needs an adapter?)

I bought an Edutige ETM 001 but it wasn't compatible. I'm told i need an Edutige EIM 001 but I'm in Asia at the moment and can't find one here...

I'd be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a couple of products from Australian microphone maker Røde.

1. Røde VideoMic Me: http://en.rode.com/microphones/videomicme
2. Røde smartLav+: http://en.rode.com/microphones/smartlav-plus

Røde makes pretty high-quality products and are leaders in making new products like these mcicrophones which are designed to plug directly into the TRRS connectors of smartphones.

I have no connection with Røde except as a satisfied, paying customer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record really good quality audio on an android smartphone (requires your phone to have USB OTG) is using an external USB soundcard like the art dual pre USB (or a any other supported soundcards) and an app called usb Audio recorder pro...

http://www.extreamsd.com/index.php/products/usb-audio-recorder-pro

With that solution you have an 80$ semi-professional sound recording solution with Phantom power etc.

Advantage is that you can use any microphone on the market with your phone.

Answer (score 0):

A compressor microphone that worked for me is the Arcano Black 01/Arcano bku-01 (those are hard to find,but they are SUPER GOOD!).Also you could go for the iRig Mic Studio,I dont know if this one works on galaxy but its a great mic!Also the iRig come with a free app to record multiple sound sources,and that is pretty handy since you are going to make a podcast.
Anyways,good luck in your podcast!

Answer (score -1):

I think you can probably get any microphone that can go into an audio slot.

Comment: This answer is not helpful because the user has already made it clear they cannot derive a specific answer from a general question.  A helpful answer would be a specific microphone recommendation that actually works with the Galaxy smartphone in question, plus some additional detail about how to then generalize that answer to other microphone options (that might be higher performance, lower cost, more readily available, etc).